# Why do Chimera Ants seem to remember only one past life?

Tags: hunter-x-hunter

Some Chimera Ants remember parts, or all, of their life before they were eaten by the Queen.

> By eating other creatures, a Chimera Ant queen can impart the characteristics of ingested creatures onto the next generation of Chimera Ants it gives birth to.

Chimera ants are shown to have characteristics that are from two, sometimes more (in the case of [Rammot](http://hunterxhunter.wikia.com/wiki/Rammot), a combination of human, rabbit and shrike) It is shown that not only human past lives can be remembered, because in Chapter 197 of the manga, [Leol](http://hunterxhunter.wikia.com/wiki/Leol) remembers being a lion.

However, the chimera ants that remember their past life seem to only remember one. Is it only possible for them to remember one? Why would this be? If they can remember more, why is this never shown?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I read/seen in the anime/manga is that they remember the memories associated with strong emotions. I.E Colt has a strong sense of protection because in his human life he was dead set on protecting his little sister. These emotions probably cause the memories to take precedence over others. There are how ever small instances that show both sides can be remembered. There is a conversation between Killua and Ikalgo, in where Ikalgo recalls his time as an octopus and always envied the graceful squid. Later when Ikalgo is with Welfin in the control room after shooting Welfin in the legs Ikalgo makes him speak of his human memories. This conversation jogs Ikalgo's memory and he starts to remember some of his past human memories as well.